# Cannot get Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

I am using **OAuth 2.0** for Authorization process.

I have requested for Authorization Code with this url:

https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=`{MY_CLIENT_ID}`

Then I was redirected to box.net login page for authorization.

I have entered credentials for my Box.net account.
Granted access for account.Then I got Authorization code which I encoded in URL and sent a request with this:

https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=`{AUTHORIZATION_CODE}&client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={MY_CLIENT_SECRET_ID}`

I got this response:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}
```

I have checked my Client Id and Client Secret Id many times. Those are correct. What can be reason for such an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the official documentation states:

> To get the access_token, you’ll need to make a POST request to https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token with the following parameters...",

Although all the parameters including `client_id`, `client_secret`, `grant_type` and code are right, if you don't make a `POST` request to the url, you will get `error: "invalid_client"`.

Try:

```
curl https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={your code}&client_id={your client id}&client_secret={your client secret}' \
-X POST
```